# Entity framework code first data annotation not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-validation

Hi I am using entity framework  code first approach for my project.
i have a class called Login as shown below

```
public class Login
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "UserName Required")]
    [DisplayName("Username")]
    [Key]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password Required")]
    [DisplayName("Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email Id Required")]
    [DisplayName("Email ID")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*$",
                                ErrorMessage = "Email Format is wrong")]

    public string Email { get; set; }



}
```

My database context is as below

```
public  class ContextDB:DbContext
{

    public DbSet<Login> LoginModel { get; set; } 
}
```

The table created in the database is Logins.

In my view the validation messages are not working.
Can anyone please help?

Comment: asp.mvc? validation on client? validation on server? validation on database?

Comment: asp.mvc validation on server

Comment: What do you mean not working? Have you checked the `ModelState` ?

Answer (score 0):

This might sound stupid bud are u sure that you are passing right class to your Login ActionResult, not some LoginViewModel or similar stuff? I know that by default some preloaded models exist, so make sure that this isnt case.